# how to convert VFPOLEDB File Type to dbase III?

Tags: c#, dbf

I want to know how to Convert dbf file type `VFPOLEDB` to `dbase III`?

```
 byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + "MyFile.dbf"); 
 bytes[0] = 3;
 File.WriteAllBytes(path + "my.dbf", bytes);
```

when open in arcmap not oppened

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833190/generating-dbase-ii-dbf-file-in-c-sharp-3-5

Answer (score 0):

`string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data` Source=C:\YourDirectory\";

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
{ 
    using (OleDbCommand scriptCommand = connection.CreateCommand()) 
    { 
        connection.Open(); 

        string vfpScript = @"USE TestDBF 
                             COPY TO OldDBaseFormatFile TYPE Fox2x 
                            USE"; 

        scriptCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        scriptCommand.CommandText = "ExecScript"; 
        scriptCommand.Parameters.Add("myScript", OleDbType.Char).Value = vfpScript; 
        scriptCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```